# Insert or save multiple rows records to database using entity framework in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I want to be able to add a dropdown list and save different selected values from it. When I add multiple rows it should be able to insert different values from the dropdown list using the code provided below. The code works fine but I want to know how can I achieve the dropdown list part.

View:

```
   @model IEnumerable<Insert_Multiple_Rows_EF_MVC.Customer>

   @{
    Layout = null;
     }


     <table id="tblCustomers" class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:150px">Name</th>
            <th style="width:150px">Country</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
       <tbody>
        @foreach (Customer customer in Model)
        {
            <tr>
     <td>@customer.Name</td>
     <td>@customer.Country</td>
     <td><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="Remove(this)" /></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtCountry" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<br />
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save All" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
        //Reference the Name and Country TextBoxes.
        var txtName = $("#txtName");
        var txtCountry = $("#txtCountry");

        //Get the reference of the Table's TBODY element.
        var tBody = $("#tblCustomers > TBODY")[0];

        //Add Row.
        var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

        //Add Name cell.
        var cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(txtName.val());

        //Add Country cell.
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        cell.html(txtCountry.val());

        //Add Button cell.
        cell = $(row.insertCell(-1));
        var btnRemove = $("<input />");
        btnRemove.attr("type", "button");
        btnRemove.attr("onclick", "Remove(this);");
        btnRemove.val("Remove");
        cell.append(btnRemove);

        //Clear the TextBoxes.
        txtName.val("");
        txtCountry.val("");
    });

    function Remove(button) {
        //Determine the reference of the Row using the Button.
        var row = $(button).closest("TR");
        var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();
        if (confirm("Do you want to delete: " + name)) {
            //Get the reference of the Table.
            var table = $("#tblCustomers")[0];

            //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
            table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);
        }
    };

    $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {
        //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
        var customers = new Array();
        $("#tblCustomers TBODY TR").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var customer = {};
            customer.Name = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
            customer.Country = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
            customers.push(customer);
        });

        //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/InsertCustomers",
            data: JSON.stringify(customers),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CustomersEntities entities = new CustomersEntities();
        return View(entities.Customers);
    }

    public JsonResult InsertCustomers(List<Customer> customers)
    {
        using (CustomersEntities entities = new CustomersEntities())
        {
            //Truncate Table to delete all old records.
            entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [Customers]");

            //Check for NULL.
            if (customers == null)
            {
                customers = new List<Customer>();
            }

            //Loop and insert records.
            foreach (Customer customer in customers)
            {
                entities.Customers.Add(customer);
            }
            int insertedRecords = entities.SaveChanges();
            return Json(insertedRecords);
        }
    }
```

Model

```
 public partial class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For add, multiple records you need to add different IDs to each textbox. You can add multiple textboxes up to 10 records (you can replace 10 by any number in Jquery code) by jquery and javascript. Here is an example.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#addButton").click(function () {
                if( ($('.form-horizontal .control-group').length+1) > 10) {
                    alert("Only 10 control-group allowed");
                    return false;
                }
                var id = ($('.form-horizontal .control-group').length + 1).toString();
                $('.form-horizontal').append('<input type="text" id="txtName' + id + '" placeholder="Name">&nbsp<input type="text" id="txtCountry' + id + '" placeholder="Country"></div></div></div>');
            });


        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
          <td><input type="text" id="txtName" placeholder="Name"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtCountry" placeholder="Country" /></td>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='Add Record' id='addButton' />
```